# How should I connect the wiring for a Rheem A/C motor?

Tags: wiring, hvac, motor

[image][image][image][image]enter image description hereI had my AC motor stolen from inside my outside Rheem unit. I installed a new motor today. I connected the `white to orange` and the `black to black` wire. I have a `red`, a `brown`, and `white` wire that I have no clue where they go. Please let me know where the 3 wires go.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look on the inside of the panel the prints are usually there if not the model # will be needed to look up the schematics. If you can share a clear infocus pic we should be able to help you. Did they cut the harness? What was left can be a clue. I am not sure why you are connecting wires when you don’t know where they go.

Comment: Hi and thank you. The model is RPMC 060JAZ I tied a white wire  on the orange wire and a black wire on the black wire to unit (see pics) when I first installed the first motor so I know they go there. Lake Charles Louisiana had 2 hurricanes so calling my local ac guy doesn't exist.  Literally half the city is pretty much gone and destroyed still.  I can do without for the summer but I hoped that my family might have ac again with the kind help of professionals here that can tell me where the other 3 wires go. The power is off to the unit of course  until I know for sure.  God bless one and all

Comment: I should have asked for the wiring on the new motor there should be a print on the side of the motor. There are several of us that do this it should be possible to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you  i posted the model and wiring info on the motor side any help enormously appreciated

Comment: Photo is clearing up must be a slow connection, the purple and purple white are the same as the brown/ brown white  and the red is line going back to the contractor , the others were the rotation as I had guessed , deleted the original comment as the photo cleared up after a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Left as an answer because the basic info is here that can be figured out without the actual motor wiring print and two long for a comment.

Can you get a clear photo of the motor wiring diagrams I can not read them on my phone.

I am in a remote site today and only have my phone connection. I can read the schematic (it’s upside down).

From what I see the original fan is single speed.
One wire goes to line side of the motor this wire connects to a temp switch and a relay.
the other 2 wires go to the start capacitor one goes to the C connection on the cap or common.
the last wire Goes to the F connection on the cap.

The new motor being multi tapped may also have a rotation with a clear photo of that we may be able to figure out the colors but it won’t be hard.

as 2 wires go directly to the cap one goes to the sensor /contactor then the line side I really need a clear photo of the motor schematic as they are all different.

Edit this may be enough info to finish the connections.
Another quick look at the wires in the photo purple and purple white are probably the cap and cap common look at the wires where they attach to the cap, the c terminal I would guess is the purple with the white stripe and the F terminal just purple , then the red would go to the line connection on the motor but I can not tell without a clear photo. I am guessing the motor connections you made were for rotation.

Comment: Thank you i uploaded this  am high resolution  pics of everything. I will be happy to pay just to get the answer to make work for my family